# Android app says it is not optimized after changing to app-bundle mechanism

Tags: android

Just changed my app-delivery to the new bundle-mechanism and now it shows "app not optimized" for tablets (tested with Google Pixel C and some 7" Lenovo Tab).

Could it be, because I only have sw600dp for handling tablets and nothing higher (sw720dp or sw1024dp)?

And is there a way to determine which device is optimized for my app and which not?

Comment: Where does it say that? In the Google Play listing? Have you added screenshots for 7" and 10" tablets?

Comment: Yeah, in the Google Play listing. The app is in the PlayStore since ~3 years and the only thing which I changed was using the app-bundle mechanism, so that our app has only 19-20MB instead of 42.
Do I need to have tablet-screenshots? Do I see if someone removed them (management)?
Edit: According to our support team, we have tablet screenshots (you see the Pixel C) and no one changed anything else at the PlayStore entry (description, etc.)

Comment: And when I use the bundletool to generate the apks, I have standalones APKs for:  ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.